# Jython in Java error: ImportError: No module named

Tags: java, macos, python-2.7, netbeans, jython-2.5

I've read A LOT about this matter but nothing seems to work with me right!
I'm using `Netbeans 8.0`
and `Python 2.6.5`, `Jython 2.5.1` (the default from adding Python and Jython Plugin to netbeans) 
I'm a `mac os x 10.9.3 user`

I tried to open a new Jython Code where I add the path to python to get it work: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` and it does.

I also tried to call a Python code from Java code using Jython and it works for simple print code. But when I add an nltk POS code (which work very fine in Python interpreter) it throws an error: ImportError: No module named nltk

I thried those Paths:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Python/2.7/site-package

when I call python from terminal the nltk import work fine:

```
Sosys-MacBook-Pro:~ ha$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ha/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin:/Users/ha/apache-opennlp-1.5.3/bin:/Users/ha/jython2.5.4rc1:/Users/ha/nltk_data:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/
Sosys-MacBook-Pro:downloads ha$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```

Then I get another error: ImportError: No module named signal. and so on with those no module named...
I also tried to add jython-standalone-2.7-b21.jar in the classpath in the Libraries but it doesn't solve this problem.

### How can I get it work?

**Appendix:**
*my Java Code:*

```
package jythonprojecttes;
import java.lang.*;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class JythonProjectTes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try
        {       
            System.out.print(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
            PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
            PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
            interp.execfile("/Users/ha/NetBeansProjects/JythonProjectTes/src/jythonprojecttes/Code.py"); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

*my Python Code:*

```
import nltk

tokenizer = None
tagger = None

def tag(sentences):
    global tokenizer
    global tagger
    tagged = nltk.sent_tokenize(sentences.strip())
    tagged = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in tagged]
    tagged = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tagged]
    return tagged

def ReadFromTXT():
    # Reading input from a file    
    Question = open('/Users/ha/NetBeansProjects/JythonNLTK/src/jythonnltk/input.txt', 'r')  
    return Question.read()

def PrintToText(tagged):
    # Writing output to file    
    output_file = open('/Users/ha/NetBeansProjects/JythonNLTK/src/jythonnltk/output.txt', 'w')
    output_file.writelines(["%s\n" % item for item in tagged])
    output_file.close()    
    print "Printed to Output.txt"

def main():
    #Only 'What be' kind of questions.
    sentences = ReadFromTXT() 
    print "The Question is:"+sentences
    tagged = tag(sentences)
    PrintToText(tagged)
    print tagged

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print sys.path
    main()
```

Thanks in advance